# Wireless Shutter Control for Sony RX 1

Tags: sony, shutter, remote, bluetooth, sony-rx100

I have an old Sony RX1 - have no Bluetooth build in.

I'm wondering if there is a tool out there that can turn my camera to be able to take a take a shot wirelessly.

[image]

I'm open to any suggestions at this moment.

Any hints/suggestions / helps on this be will be much appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify if you talk about RX1 or A7 camera (or RX100 as per tag)

Answer (score 1):

You can use mechanical shutter like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0031CGW7E) or [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Remote-Shutter-Release-Control-RM-VPR1-for-SONY-RX1-A7-NEX-3N-DSC-HX60-RX100-III-/281747642832) for example. Unfortunately Sony do not include any wireless option in RX1 (which IMHO is shame for almost 3000$ camera...)

Found one DIY project where you can create wireless mechanical shutter [here](https://www.instructables.com/id/Remote-Mechanical-Shutter-Release/)

P.S. No affiliate with sites and sellers

Comment: Do u any tools that can trigger remote shutter ?

Comment: @kyo  yes, I found one article about. Will add it in to the answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about RX1, but RX100 (as per tag) can be paired with a phone over WiFi for remote shooting - Sony has [a special app](https://www.playmemoriescameraapps.com/portal/usbdetail.php?eid=IS9104-NPIA09014_00-F00002) for it. RX1RM2 is actually listed there too in the compatibility list.

I used it years ago, it's functional, but in a typical Sony fashion, not as usable as it could easily be done.

Comment: RX1RM2 have wireless connectivity RX1 don't